# How many vertices is to many for a polygon

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx, polygon, polygons

Would it be considered bad to have to many vertices to define a single polygon. What I mean is if a lot of the coordinates are touching is that bad? I am worried about what will happened when I come to triangulate my polygons as well as performance issues (technically this is not a problem for the size of the game, but I want to take it into consideration for my own personal development).

[note] - this is a libgdx project. I am making risk the board game. The polygons are for mapping territories that are (obviously) complex and irregular shapes.

Comment: This is a really interesting question! I don't think there is any way to know how badly the performance will be affected by such irregular shapes being rendered. Out of curiosity, how many vertices do some polygons have? I don't think it's possible to render the countries as textures is it? In this case I'd imagine the best way to deal with this problem I'd the way you are doing it at the moment!

Comment: If you're using ShapeRenderer, more than a few thousand vertices drawn at once will cause frame rate slowdown on low-to-mid range phones. To represent a world map like Risk's well, it would almost certainly be better performing and looking to use textures.

Comment: I am going to be using spriteBatch and polygonRegion. And this is for desktop.

Comment: I am also not sure how I can triangulate these polygons...I think there is going to be <1000 vertices and some are close together. I wrote my own shape to polygon program, which I know is really shit, but I could not find anything else.